# Spark History-Server does not shows logs for some applications

Tags: apache-spark

Spark History-Server (Version-3.2.1, Hadoop-3.1.1)is not showing logs for some application, even though the spark-events path in HDFS is same for across the application logs.

If I restart the History-Server it shows logs(for apps which was not showing earlier) , but after sometime it wont show for some new-set of applications.

This issue is happening for random application, not able to identify the pattern.

```
23/08/16 20:59:40 INFO FsHistoryProvider: Parsing hdfs://stagehdfs/spark3-history/application_1678437047884_599309_1.inprogress for listing data...
23/08/16 20:59:40 INFO FsHistoryProvider: Parsing hdfs://stagehdfs/spark3-history/application_1678437047884_599304_1 for listing data...
23/08/16 20:59:40 INFO FsHistoryProvider: Looking for end event; skipping 112931832 bytes from hdfs://stagehdfs/spark3-history/application_1678437047884_599304_1...
23/08/16 20:59:40 INFO FsHistoryProvider: Finished parsing hdfs://stagehdfs/spark3-history/application_1678437047884_599304_1
23/08/16 20:59:40 INFO FsHistoryProvider: Finished parsing hdfs://stagehdfs/spark3-history/application_1678437047884_599309_1.inprogress
23/08/16 21:00:47 INFO FsHistoryProvider: Parsing hdfs://stagehdfs/spark3-history/application_1678437047884_599319_1.inprogress for listing data...
23/08/16 21:00:47 INFO FsHistoryProvider: Parsing hdfs://stagehdfs/spark3-history/application_1678437047884_599318_1.inprogress for listing data...
23/08/16 21:00:47 INFO FsHistoryProvider: Parsing hdfs://stagehdfs/spark3-history/application_1678437047884_599317_1.inprogress for listing data...
23/08/16 21:00:47 INFO FsHistoryProvider: Finished parsing hdfs://stagehdfs/spark3-history/application_1678437047884_599318_1.inprogress
23/08/16 21:00:47 INFO FsHistoryProvider: Finished parsing hdfs://stagehdfs/spark3-history/application_1678437047884_599319_1.inprogress
23/08/16 21:00:47 INFO FsHistoryProvider: Finished parsing hdfs://stagehdfs/spark3-history/application_1678437047884_599317_1.inprogress
23/08/16 21:02:24 INFO FsHistoryProvider: Parsing hdfs://stagehdfs/spark3-history/application_1678437047884_599319_1 for listing data...
23/08/16 21:02:24 INFO FsHistoryProvider: Looking for end event; skipping 82041452 bytes from hdfs://stagehdfs/spark3-history/application_1678437047884_599319_1...
23/08/16 21:02:24 INFO FsHistoryProvider: Finished parsing hdfs://stagehdfs/spark3-history/application_1678437047884_599319_1
23/08/16 21:02:24 ERROR Utils: Uncaught exception in thread log-replay-executor-7
java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at org.apache.spark.util.kvstore.InMemoryStore.read(InMemoryStore.java:85)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider.$anonfun$checkAndCleanLog$3(FsHistoryProvider.scala:927)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider.$anonfun$checkAndCleanLog$1(FsHistoryProvider.scala:926)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLog(Utils.scala:2032)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider.checkAndCleanLog(FsHistoryProvider.scala:916)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider.mergeApplicationListing(FsHistoryProvider.scala:712)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider.$anonfun$checkForLogs$15(FsHistoryProvider.scala:576)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
23/08/16 21:02:34 INFO FsHistoryProvider: Parsing hdfs://stagehdfs/spark3-history/application_1678437047884_599318_1 for listing data...
23/08/16 21:02:34 INFO FsHistoryProvider: Looking for end event; skipping 82754288 bytes from hdfs://stagehdfs/spark3-history/application_1678437047884_599318_1...
```

Can any one help me on this..
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug in spark 3.2.1.
Please refer to the below.

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-39083
- https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/36424
- https://git.odin.cse.buffalo.edu/ODIn/spark-instrumented-optimizer/commit/29643265a9f5e8142d20add5350c614a55161451?style=unified&whitespace=ignore-all&show-outdated=
- Affects Version/s: 3.2.1
- Fix Version/s:3.3.0, 3.2.2